# Problems with pcolormesh in Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to adapt the Cartopy [example plot](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/always_circular_stereo.html) for circular South Polar Stereographic plots to the North Pole and add data to it. I have a couple questions.

First, in the example code, the land feature is added before the ocean feature. When I did that, I got a map with only ocean. I reversed the order of the call in the code below and get a map with land and ocean. Why did the other order work with the South Polar example?

Second, and more importantly, I can't figure out why my pcolormesh call isn't having any effect.

I'm using Python 2.7.7, matplotlib 1.5.1, and Cartopy 0.15.1.

```
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature

lats = np.linspace(60,90,30)
lons = np.linspace(0,360,200)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
Z = np.random.normal(size = X.shape)

def main():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 5])
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95,
                        left=0.04, right=0.95, wspace=0.02)

    # Limit the map to -60 degrees latitude and below.
    ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 60, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.gridlines()

    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)

    # Compute a circle in axes coordinates, which we can use as a boundary
    # for the map. We can pan/zoom as much as we like - the boundary will be
    # permanently circular.
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
    verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
    circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)

    ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)
    ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())


    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code leaves **cartopy** to dictate the order of feature plots on the map, as a result, some features can be hidden with no clues. It is possible to specify the order of plots explicitly.

The order of features plot is controlled by zorder, which can be specified with `zorder=integer` in most plotting statements. Here is a modified code that produces a better plot.

```
# your data
lats = np.linspace(60, 90, 30)
lons = np.linspace(0, 360, 160)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
Z = np.random.normal(size = X.shape)

# new data for pcolormesh plot
latz = np.linspace(75, 90, 15)
lonz = np.linspace(0, 360, 160)
X1,Y1 = np.meshgrid(lonz, latz)
Z1 = np.random.normal(size = X1.shape)

def main():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95,
                        left=0.04, right=0.95, wspace=0.02)

    # Limit the map to -60 degrees latitude and below.
    ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 60, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.gridlines()

    # zorder can be used to arrange what is on top
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=4)   # land is specified to plot above ...
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=1)  # ... the ocean

    # Compute a circle in axes coordinates, which we can use as a boundary
    # for the map. We can pan/zoom as much as we like - the boundary will be
    # permanently circular.
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
    verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
    circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)

    ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)
    # pcolormesh is specified to plot on top of the ocean but below land
    ax.pcolormesh(X1, Y1, Z1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=3)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like this was the problem, thanks. Can I ask why you decided to use a different lat/lon grid, and why you chose layers 1,3,4 instead of 0,1,2?

Comment: I focus on the order of features plotting. If I use your data for `pcolormesh()` plot, all the ocean (and the graticule) will be hidden by pcolormesh layer. For values of zorder, they are used to set the order of plotting, thus, allowing us to produce what we need. Values (1,3,4) can produce different or same output with (0,1,2). Note that, ax.gridlines() can also have zorder=some_value, you can bring it on top of the plot with a value you can guess. To obtain a nicer map, there are other factors to consider.